# How to merge a pandas df with a geopandas df for plotting on a shapefile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I am playing with the following shapefile that can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/joncutrer/geopandas-tutorial/tree/master/data). I'm not going to include the output but here is the code that reads it in as a geopandas df and plots the shapefile.

```
states = geopandas.read_file('usa-states-census-2014.shp')
states.head()

states.plot()
```

I also have the following df, which is the `USArrests` dataset which can be found [here on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/deepakg/usarrests).

What I am trying to do is merge the two datasets so I can plot the shapefile with a colormap of the features in `USArrests`. I ran the following code to merge the datasets.

```
df = pd.read_csv("USArrests.csv")
df.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 0':'NAME'}, inplace = True)
merged = pd.merge(df, states, on=['NAME']).drop_duplicates(subset=['NAME'])
```

The merge worked, but now when I run `states.plot()` I get a line plot, and I'm assuming this is because the df is no longer a `GeoDataFrame`.

My quesiton is, how can I take the data from `USArrests` and use it to plot a colormap over the shapefile? Thanks!

Note, I am using the following [guide](https://jcutrer.com/python/learn-geopandas-plotting-usmaps) to help me but it doesn't cover my specific task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GeoDataFrame.merge` method. That way it remains GeoDataFrame. What happened in your case is that `merged` is pandas.DataFrame only.

```py
merged = states.merge(df, on='NAME').drop_duplicates(subset=['NAME'])
```

I am guessing the correct form a bit as you did not show the structure of any of your data frames. See the documentation for more https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html?highlight=merge#attribute-joins